# ASP.Net Core 2.2 or 3.1 SPA with React and Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, .net-core

I am trying two days already to containerize ASP.NET Core 2.2, but without any luck, I have read most than 20 articles about it, and I am not sure if it is even possible. It leads me to an error page stating that it cannot find npm and to check if it exists and is added to `PATH`.

I tried adding this

```
RUN apt-get install --yes curl
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs
```

to the dockerfile, also added **/node_modules to the `.dockerignore` file as I read in the articles but without luck

Read that someone has succeeded on .NET Core 2.1, but I haven't tried it because it won't work for me. Can someone please share if it is possible with dot net core 2.2 or above, I can settle for 2.2, 3.0, 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do it.

the trick was to use another image (`node:13-alpine`) to do the `npm install` and to add a condition in the `.cproj` file for the publish part.

It is explained better in this article:

[Link](http://parsstudent.com/asp-net-core-npm-error-when-generating-a-docker-image-of-a-project-created-with-the-react-template/)